# What Is Difference Between The echo() Statement And The print() Statement In PHP?

Tags: php, printing, echo

```
<?php
print();#The Print Statement
echo();#The Echo Statement
?>
```

## I Would Be Very Thankful If Someone Answered My Question...

Comment: If I remember correctly print has a return value and echo doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` returns a value (always `1`); `echo` returns nothing

`echo` will accept multiple arguments, `print` only accepts one argument